# LibreOffice + TeXmath on Using Chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

With the LaTeX example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  elmove/.style={-{Stealth[#1]},shorten >=3pt,shorten <=2pt}
}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
 \chemfig{@{Cl1}\lewis{2:4:6:,Cl}-[@{b}]@{Cl2}\lewis{0:2:6:,Cl}}
\arrow(--plus){0}[,.1]
\+
\arrow{0}[,.1]
\chemfig{@{C}\lewis{4.,C}H_3}
\arrow
\chemfig{\lewis{0.2:4:6:,Cl}}
\chemsign{+}  \chemfig{\lewis{2:4:6:,Cl}-CH_3}
\schemestop
  \chemmove{
\path (plus) ++(45:4mm) coordinate (nb) ;   
\draw[elmove=left]
        (b) ..controls +(-90:7mm) and +(-90:7mm) .. (Cl1) ;
\draw[elmove=left]
    (b) ..controls + (80:10mm) and +(100:7mm) .. (plus) ;  
\draw[elmove=right]
        (C) ++(-.25,0) ..controls + (80:7mm) and +(80:6mm) .. (plus) ;
 }
\end{document}
```

I get the output

[image]

I tried to use LibreOffice and TeXmath I transferred it and input the preamble:

[image]

but instead got this as a result:

[image]

```
any idea how to fix this?
```

Comment: Minimising your preamble, the issue is clear: the arrow placement is only correct on the _second_ TeX run and requires information from the first run. I'm guessing TeXmath does a simple one-pass run, so unless that is configurable you are out of luck.

Comment: I was also suspecting that as the case.. as a latex document it normally requires 2 compiles before the arrows can be set correctly.. Any way thank you so much for you help and advice.